# P thread - cast to pointer from integer of different size

Tags: c, pthreads

So I am trying to figure out why I am getting this error in regards to p thread.

I get the below error when I'm trying to run the code. I know it has to be something with p thread but not sure exactly what it is.

```
prime.c: In function ‘main’:
prime.c:33: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
prime.c: In function ‘isPrime’:
prime.c:50: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
```

any idea of what I'm doing wrong?  I am including my code below. Thanks in advance for help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int *ptr;
int count;
int n;
void *isPrime(void *argp);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int i;
    int num = 2;
    int p;
    pthread_t tid;

    count = 0;  

    if (argc == 2 || argc == 3) {       
        printf("Argument : %s\n", argv[1]);
        n = atoi(argv[1]);
        if (argc == 3) {
            p = atoi(argv[2]);
        }
        else {
            p = 1;
        }

        ptr = (int *) malloc(n*sizeof(int));

        while (count <= n) {
             for (i = 1; i <= p; i++)
                pthread_create(&tid, NULL, isPrime, (void *)num++);

        }

        for ( i = 0;i < n; i++) {
            printf("%d ", *(ptr+i));
        }

    }
    else {
        printf("Invalid number of arguments\n");
    }
}


void *isPrime(void *vargp) {
    int i,flag = 0;
    int num = (int)vargp;       
    for (i = 2; i <= num/2; i++) {
        if (num % i == 0) {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!flag && count <= n) {
        *(ptr + count) = num;
        count++;
    }


}
```

Comment: `#include <stdint.h>`, then use `intptr_t` for your values masquerading as `void*`; not `int`. And please note the *lines* where your errors are happening, preferably with comments in the source code to match. 33 and 50 mean nothing unless this is a verbatim copy of the entire source file (which it may be, but always a good habit none-the-less).

Comment: It's even better to avoid casting between `int`s and pointers in the first place, and just pass a valid pointer when one is expected.

Comment: As much as I dread telling you this, the warning is the least of your worries. This code has multiple issues including, but not limited to, race-conditions, failure to properly join child threads, and the thread proc that has no `return` statement. The warning you can address by refactoring the code utilizing my first comment, but the real problems will rear their ugly heads even after that is done.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the obvious way to avoid the implementation-defined behavior inherent in casting between integers and pointers:

```
while (count <= n) {
    for (i = 1; i <= p; i++) {
        int * iptr = malloc(sizeof *iptr);
        if ( !iptr ) {
            perror("Couldn't allocate memory.");  /*  Or other failure code  */
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        *iptr = num++;
        pthread_create(&tid, NULL, isPrime, iptr);
    }
}
```

and then in your thread function:

```
void *isPrime(void *vargp) {
    int * iptr = vargp;
    int num = *iptr;
    free(iptr);

    /*  Rest of function  */

    return NULL;
}
```

As @WhozCraig points out, this is only one of the thread-related problems in your code.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

As WhozCraig and  user3386109 point out, the changes I suggest below introduce a race condition.  I haven't encountered this exact use case (passing different values to different threads through a single variable), so I can't offer any useful advice; simply take the explanation for why the warnings occur as what they are.

**Original**

> pthread_create(&tid, NULL, isPrime, (void *)num++);

The expression `(void *)num++` attempts to convert the type of the expression `num++` to `void *`; since integers and pointers may have different sizes and representations, this is potentially a bad idea.

<strike>Ideally, you should do something more like the following:</strike>

```
{
  pthread_create( &tid, NULL, isPrime, (void *) &num );
  num++;
}
```

Unfortunately, `(void *) &num++` won't work; the result of the `++` operator isn't an lvalue, so you can't apply the `&` operator to it.

`(void *) &num` is converting from one pointer type to `void *`, which is safer than converting from an integer type to a pointer type.

Then, in the `isprime` function, you would need to make the corresponding change:

```
int num = *((int *)vargp);
```

That is, convert `vargp` back to a pointer to `int` and dereference it.

Comment: Um, you missed the part where every thread gets a different value for `num`. If you pass the address of `num` to the threads, then you create a race condition where the value of `num` could change before or while the thread is accessing `num`.

Comment: Passing `num` by address is not the way to do this. You will introduce a race condition between the launched thread acquiring its ID and the main thread incrementing `num` (and likely the reason the OP is passing by value in the first place).

Comment: @WhozCraig: indeed so.  Sigh.

Comment: @JohnBode no worries, the OP probably doesn't realize the race on `count` anyway, so just most stuff to think about.

Comment: @WhozCraig So what is the correct way to correct this?

Comment: @Rob see my comment in general-comments. The short of it is, you can properly ditch the warning utilizing my first comment (thats one way, anyway), but there are some serious concerns after that you need to account for.